# How to show all intermediate views when updating state in a loop, swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

how can I force the view to update reflecting ALL @State changes, but not jumping from the initial to the final one?

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @State var counter = 0

    func updatecounter(){
        for _ in 1...10{withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 1)){counter+=1}}
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Counter: \(self.counter)")
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {self.updatecounter()}){Text("Update Counter")}
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {static var previews: some View {ContentView()}}
```

I want the code above to show all the numbers from 1 to 10 when a button is clicked (1,2,3,4,5...), and not jumping from 1 to 10 right away, as it currently does.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the nature of SwiftUI is to simply *react* to state changes - and since you are updating your counter *almost* immediately from 1-10, you need to slow your model down. You really aren't saying why/what you are trying here, so my initial thought is to (a) move your code into a *true* model and attach a Timer to it. Set it to update at some interval (0.3 seconds?) and it should work. Of course, if your app is some game with actual logic behind updating the counter, then your code really isn't close to what you should be doing.

Comment: Thanks. I was just wondering if that think can work without a timer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Timer publisher to make sequential animation in SwiftUI:

```
                   import Combine

          @State var counter = 0
          @State  var cancelable : AnyCancellable?

            func updatecounter(){

                 cancelable   =    Timer.publish(every: 1, on: RunLoop.main, in: RunLoop.Mode.default).autoconnect().sink { (Date) in
                     withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: 1)){
                        self.counter += 1
                    }
                    if self.counter == 10 {
                              self.cancelable?.cancel() }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and the code. It does the job. I was just hoping that there is an easier way to achieve the same thing without a timer.